# How to see conversation history in "Pidgin Messenger" when using Ubuntu?

Tags: pidgin

I use "***Pidgin***" on Ubuntu instead of Yahoo Messenger, and i recently noticed that when i am offline and somebody writes me, "***Pidgin***" won't show it to me as offline messages, or when i write to my friend by "***Pidgin***" while my friend is offline, he won't get my offline messages either, and i didn't see an option to see conversation history. how can i fix these 3 problems?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All the messenger logs will be stored under `.purple` directory located in your home directory.

```
cd ~/.purple/logs/yahoo/
```

this is the location where all your yahoo messenger chat logs will be stored.

You can also view the logs by selecting **"Conversation -> View Log**" when you have the contact window opened.

To send a message to a offline contact, use "Offline Message Emulation". Open "**Tool->Plugins**" and make sure you have selected "**Offline Message Emulation**". This will save the message you sent to a offline contact and the message will be delivered once he is online.

If you are offline and a contact sends you a message that will be delivered to you when you come online.

There are other good plugins for pidgin. To install the extra plugins use the command

```
 sudo apt-get install pidgin-plugin-pack
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, pidgin not showing offline messages, like if i go offline and someone sends me message today.. and i login after two days.. it does not shows me the offline messages.. even i have checked the `Offline Message Emulation` please suggest some plugins..

Answer (score 20):

If you enable the "History" plugin, recent conversations will be shown in message windows. I find that very useful.

Comment: I wish there was a way to extend the range, or configure some stuff, unfortunately, this plugin has no configuration options. Still nice to have the previous conversation though.

Comment: Where should I be able to see the history? I enabled the plugin but cannot notice any change.